Subcodes of Reed-Solomon codes
I would like to create a list of meaningful subcodes of Reed-Solomon codes. By "meaningful" I mean codes that have their own interest in some area of information theory.
For example, Tamo-Barg codes are optimal locally recoverable that are used in distributed storage systems and are realized as subcodes of Reed-Solomon codes.
https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.3284
Any other?

One place to go to start building such a list might be the Error-Correcting Code Zoo. It’s still under construction, of course, but it’s probably the best place to have a mass of collected connections between different families of codes that I can think of, outside of a textbook.
